# Does Gauss' theorem and Stokes' theorem still hold for distributions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, vector-analysis, distribution-theory

We can define the derivative of distributions and then we can define their grad, div and curl, so do the Stokes' theorem and Gauss' theorem still hold for distributions? if not, under which condition can these two theorems hold?

Comment: The space $\mathscr{D}$ of test functions is (sequentially) dense in that $\mathscr{D}'$ of distributions. The distributional derivative is the unique continuous extension of the ordinary derivative on $\mathscr{D}$. So if you have a linear identity true for nice smooth functions, you automatically have it for distributions too. Now the issue with integral theorems of multivariate calculus is they involve restrictions to submanifolds. Distributions typically don't like that.

Comment: The problem here is that distributions don't necessarily have a well defined trace on the  boundary of a domain. For example, a function $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ has no well-defined pointwise values. So you cannot write $\int_a^b f'(x) dx = f(b) - f(a)$, which would be the simplest version of the Gauss theorem.

Answer (score 2):

The divergence theorem is in general inapplicable but if $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\operatorname{sing supp}\vec{F} \cap \partial\Omega = \emptyset$ then $\iint \vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}\,dS$  is defined and one can even define $\vec{F} \chi_\Omega$ as a distribution. Take $\rho \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\rho\equiv 1$ on a neighborhood of $\Omega$. Then $\langle (\nabla\cdot\vec{F}) \chi_\Omega, \rho \rangle = \iint \vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}\,dS$. Abusing integral notation we can write $\langle (\nabla \cdot \vec{F}) \chi_\Omega, \rho\rangle$ as $\iiint_\Omega \nabla\cdot\vec{F}\,dV$ so that Gauss' theorem holds.

Computation:
$$
0  = -\langle \vec{F}\chi_\Omega \stackrel{\bullet}{,} \nabla\rho \rangle = \langle \nabla\cdot(\vec{F}\chi_\Omega), \rho \rangle = \langle (\nabla\cdot\vec{F})\chi_\Omega, \rho \rangle + \langle \vec{F}\cdot\nabla\chi_\Omega, \rho \rangle \\ = \langle (\nabla\cdot\vec{F})\chi_\Omega, \rho \rangle - \iint \vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}\,dS .
$$

Comment: what does the product of two distributions mean?

Comment: In general the product of two distributions isn't defined, but if their singular supports are disjoint it can be defined since each of them is a smooth function on the other's singular support.

Comment: If there is no sing supp on the boundary of a volume then does gauss theorem holds?@md2perpe

Comment: and could you please tell me whether the stokes theorem holds under the condition mentioned in your answer?@md2perpe

Comment: I modified the condition; $\vec F$ should not be singular on $\partial\Omega.$ It's okay if it is singular on the inner of $\Omega.$

Comment: Gauss' theorem can be said to hold under this condition. The boundary integral is well-defined, the integral of the divergence over the region can be defined, and the values of these coincide. Also Stokes' theorem should hold under the same condition.